# Как сделать диалоговое окно в Unity 3D?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Вроде бы, всё должно быть предельно просто, но в поисковиках не могу найти именно то, что надо... А надо примерно следующее: при клике мышкой по объекту появляется полупрозрачное окошко (почти во всю ширину экрана), содержащее изображение, заголовок, обычный текст и кнопочку закрытия этого самого окна. HELP!

Comment: Возможно поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423389/how-to-create-a-dialogue-box-and-display-it-when-an-object-in-clicked-in-unity-3

Comment: Определённо полезная информация, спасибо!

Comment: Вы используете Unity UI, Legacy UI, или это безразлично? На всякий случай, Unity UI - это современная система пользовательских интерфейсов, которая основана на ГО и редактируется в визуальном конструкторе. Legacy UI - это старая система, интерфейсы редактируются только с помощью кода.

Comment: Конечно, не имея должного опыта в ковырянии скриптов, лучше Unity UI. Но не принципиально, главное добиться желаемого результата.

Comment: В новом UI создаете префаб из канваса с нужным вам содержимым, и показываете при необходимости показать диалог.... Такого понятия как  диалоговое окно в Unity3d нет, поскольку оно подразумевает окно отличное от оригинала, что в играх просто не используется... И все 'всплывающие' окна реализуются разной Z составляющей у элементов UI. PS: И [Google](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window) как всегда знает ответ.